# Module naming convention: Reserved prefix for internal distributions?

Tags: perl, naming-conventions, cpan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I choose a package name for a custom Perl module that does not collide with builtin or CPAN packages names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658955/how-do-i-choose-a-package-name-for-a-custom-perl-module-that-does-not-collide-wi)

Suppose I'm creating set of modules/classes for our company called ACME, a pillow manufacturer:

```
Pillow;
Pillow::Bed;
Pillow::Orthopedic;
Pillow::Decorative;
```

Now to avoid conflict with other modules I might want to use in future, I'd rather prefix all names with `ACME::`:

```
ACME::Pillow;
ACME::Pillow::Bed;
ACME::Pillow::Orthopedic;
ACME::Pillow::Decorative;
```

But in some cases this might not be enough. Sometimes the company name might be "weak" and potentially get in conflict with future modules (or even already conflict with existing ones).

Is there any conventional prefix that is specifically reserved for such use?

(If it was e-mail headers, I'd use `X-ACME`, but in this case the `X::` is already taken...)

Comment: @cjm Yep, bad search--the other one already has a perfect answer :) Thanks.