# What is the error in this object oriented program?

Tags: perl, oop

I am learning perl and when I tried to do object orientation, I encountered errors,
This is the code, Test.pm

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl 

package Test;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _firstName => shift,
        _lastName  => shift,
        _ssn       => shift,
    };
    # Print all the values just for clarification.
    print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";
    print "SSN is $self->{_ssn}\n";
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub setFirstName {
    my ( $self, $firstName ) = @_;
    $self->{_firstName} = $firstName if defined($firstName);
    return $self->{_firstName};
}

sub getFirstName {
    my( $self ) = @_;
    return $self->{_firstName};
}
1;
```

and test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test;
$object = Test::new( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345); # Get first name which is set using constructor.
$firstName = $object->getFirstName();

print "Before Setting First Name is : $firstName\n";

# Now Set first name using helper function.
$object->setFirstName( "Mohd." );

# Now get first name set by helper function.
$firstName = $object->getFirstName();
print "Before Setting First Name is : $firstName\n";
```

and when I try to run, It shows some erroe like this,

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Test" at test.pl line 2.
```

What is the error in this object oriented program?

Comment: you want to do `my $object = Test->new(...)` and you also want `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of all your perl files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test is the name of a module that is part of the standard distribution of perl.  Your `use Test` is loading that instead of your Test; pick another name for your module.

Comment: @ApoorvaShankar, you might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/659198/8355) to the question [How do I choose a package name for a custom Perl module that does not collide with builtin or CPAN packages names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/658955/8355)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you already have a module named Test.pm at some other location in your default included directories.

Try running perl as:

```
perl -I./ test.pl
```

That will prepend the directory ./  (ie. the current directory) to the beginning of @INC (which is a special variable containing a list of directories to load modules from).

Answer (score 3):

`Test` is a preexisting Perl module, and it is found in `@INC` before the `Test.pm` in your current directory. (You're loading the wrong `Test.pm`.)

Rename your module to `MyTest` or similar.