# Perl module naming convention

Tags: perl, package, naming-conventions

I have checked
[*On the Naming of Modules*](http://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_namingmodules),
[`perldoc perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and
[`perldoc perlmod`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)
but can not find best practices for naming modules whose name is an acronym: `SMTP`, `ORM`.

At once on CPAN both variants names are seen: `SMTP` and `Smtp`

If my new module name is an acronymthen
what would be the better name for it: `My::Module::Abcd` or `My::Module::ABCD`?

Comment: If you look at the `Net::` namespace, where a lot of network protocols are implemented, and the ones that are just acronyms, are all using uppercases... (I am sure you can find counter examples with a fine search, but look at the vast majority). But I am speaking about acronyms, not abbreviations. Abbreviations could be find as `Abbr` I guess, in all generalities (just post the true name involved if you want people to help you on your specific name issue).

Comment: From the first link, pick whichever one is better at helping people find your module.

Answer (score 3):

In naming convention for Perl, aside from reserved you get to choose a naming convention that can be understood among those you work with. No module that starts with keywords or reserved prefix will be accepted to CPAN or the core.

So you can either choose to adopt `My::Module::Abcd` or `My::Module::ABCD` as long as you chose to adopt one that will helping people find your module.

Alternatively, you can use an underscore in the top-level name (like `My_Corp::Session` or just `My_Session`).  All categories with an underscore have also been reserved.  (This is mentioned in [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html), under "Select a name for the module".)

Note that both those reservations apply only to the top-level name.  For example, there are CPAN modules named `Time::Local` and `Text::CSV_XS`.  But `Local::Time` and `Text_CSV::XS` are reserved names and would not be accepted on CPAN.

Naming modules after your company is fine too.  (Well, unless you work for some really generic sounding company.)  Using the reverse domain name is probably overkill, unless you intend to distribute your modules to others.  (But in that case, you should probably register a normal module name.)

You might want to take a long at [How do I choose a package name for a custom Perl module that does not collide with builtin or CPAN packages names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658955/how-do-i-choose-a-package-name-for-a-custom-perl-module-that-does-not-collide-wi/659198#659198)

Comment: I am confused: documentation restricts usage of underscore: '"Other modules normally begin with a capital letter and use mixed case with no underscores"'